# How can I make a transfer function for an RC circuit in python

Tags: python, function, filter, transfer, rc

I'm fairly new to programming, but this problem happens in python and in excel as well.

I'm using the following formulas for the RC transfer function

> *s/(s+1)* for High Pass
>
> *1/(s+1)* for Low Pass
>
> with *s = jwRC*

below is the code I used in python

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
from cmath import *

"""
Generating a transfer function for RC filters.
Importing modules for complex math and plotting.
"""

f = arange(1, 5000, 1)
w = 2.0j*pi*f
R=100
C=1E-5


hp_tf = (w*R*C)/(w*R*C+1)  # High Pass Transfer function
lp_tf = 1/(w*R*C+1)    # Low Pass Transfer function

plot(f, hp_tf) # plot high pass transfer function
plot(f, lp_tf, '-r') # plot low pass transfer function
xscale('log')
```

I can't post images yet so I can't show the plot.  But the issue here is the cutoff frequency is different for each one.  They should cross at y=0.707, but they actually cross at about 0.5.

I figure my formula or method is wrong somewhere, but I can't find the mistake can anyone help me out?

Also, on a related note, I tried to convert to dB scale and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I'm using the following

```
debl=20*log(hp_tf)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical example why you should avoid `pylab` and more generally imports of the form

```
 from module import *
```

unless you know exactly what it does, since it hopelessly clutters the name space.

Using,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

and then calling `np.log` and `plt.plot` etc. will solve your problem.

---

**Furether explanations**

What's happening here is that,

```
from pylab import *
```

defines a `log` function from `numpy` that operate on arrays (the one you want).

However, the later import,

```
from cmath import *
```

overwrites it with a version that only accepts scalars, hence your error.

Comment: Ok thanks, that solved the dB scale issue.  I just realized my mistake in the transfer function as well.  I had to plot the magnitudes instead of just the raw complex result.